# problem with setSelectedValue Method for JList

Tags: java, jlist

i am having troubles when i run the main class for the application. The fact is that the setSelectedValue method doesn't work.
the code for the main class is the following:

```
DatabaseConnection.getInstance().connect("org.sqlite.JDBC", "jdbc:sqlite:db/Universidad.sqlite");
DatabaseTableManagers managers = DatabaseTableManagers.getInstance();
DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().setSelectedValue("Alumnos");
system.out.println(DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().devolver() + "1");
    AlumnosTableManager atm = AlumnosTableManager.getInstance();
    System.out.println(DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().devolver() + "2");
    CarrerasTableManager ctm = CarrerasTableManager.getInstance();
    System.out.println(DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().devolver() + "3");
    managers.add(atm);
    System.out.println(DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().devolver() + "4");
    managers.add(ctm);
    System.out.println(DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().devolver() + "5");
    DataBaseManagerJFrame dbmf = new DataBaseManagerJFrame();
    System.out.println(DataBaseManagerJList.getInstance().devolver() + "6");
    dbmf.setVisible(true);


}
```

}

and i get the following result in console which shows me that the method doesn't set the default value i've put:
null1
null2
null3
null4
null5
null6

the code for the jlist class is the following:
    public class DataBaseManagerJList extends JPanel
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static JList tablas;

DefaultListModel model;
DatabaseTableManagers dtm = DatabaseTableManagers.getInstance();
private static DataBaseManagerJList instance = null;

public static DataBaseManagerJList getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new DataBaseManagerJList();
    }
    return instance;
}

public DataBaseManagerJList()
{
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<String>(dtm.getTableNames());
    for(int i =0;i<aux.size();i++)
    {
        model.addElement(aux.get(i));
    }
    tablas = new JList(model);  
    //tablas.setSelectedValue("Alumnos",true);
    add(tablas);
}

public String devolver()
{
    return (String) tablas.getSelectedValue(); 
}


public void setSelectedValue(String name)
{

    tablas.setSelectedValue(name, true);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post what's inside of aux (capitalized exactly as it is)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing usually means that the object wasn't found in the list. 
The `setSelectedValue()` method works doing calls to `object.equals()` (in your case `String.equals()`), so the probable cause is that the strings contained in aux are capitalized  in a different way than the string you are trying to select.

For instace `aux` may contain the string "alumnos" instead of "Alumnos". There are two alternatives for this, if you don't care about capitalization (then change the string "Alumnos" to whatever is inside `aux`) if you do care about the capitalization and you still want to use strings, you could simple create a MyString class that extends String and overrides the equals method, something like:

```
public class MyString extends String {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof String){
            String obj2 = (String)obj;
            return this.equalsIgnoreCase(obj2);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Another alternative (perhaps a nicer one) is to create a wrapper object for your list.

```
public class MyWrapper {
    private String payload;

    public MyWrapper(String payload){
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return payload;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof MyWrapper){
            MyWrapper obj2 = (MyWrapper)obj;
            return payload.equalsIgnoreCase(obj2.payload);
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```